Can a non-Lie quotient of $GL_3(\mathbb{R})$ be $O_3(\mathbb{R}$)?
Recently a friend from my twitch stream asked me about the following question:

Does there exist a normal subgroup $N\leq G=GL_3(\mathbb{R})$ such that $G/N\cong O_3(\mathbb{R})$?

We know a lot about the normal subgroups of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$; in particular $N$ must either contain $SL_3(\mathbb{R})$ or be a subgroup of the center, in particular consisting of scalar matrices (see, for instance, Normal subgroups of GL$(n,\mathbb{R})$ and SL$(n,\mathbb{R})$). Therefore, if $N$ is assumed to be a Lie subgroup, it cannot exist because of a simple dimension-counting argument.
However, while it seems obvious that a non-Lie subgroup won't do the trick either, I wasn't able to see how to proceed. Even these subgroups are quite restricted by the normality condition, but how can we make use of that restriction?

What does $\cong$ mean in your question? An algebraic isomorphism? A homeomorphism? A bijection?

Hmmm, well what we want is just isomorphism of groups (not respecting any other structure). But I admit I wasn't being super careful on this point; maybe the dimension-counting argument implicitly assumes that it's a Lie group isomorphism? The argument in the link, at least, seems to rely only on the group structure of $G$.

Then you should start by proving that the quotient has to be abelian if the kernel contains $SL(3,R)$. And, yes, the dimension counting argument assumes an isomorphism of topological groups.

Consider the matrix of a transvection $M=Id+E_{1,2}$, for instance, where $E_{1,2} e_2=e_1, E_{1,2} e_1=E_{1,2}e_3=0$ : $M$ is of infinite order and conjugate to any of is power $M^n$. But a rotation cannot be conjugate to its power as it as an angle. So the image of $M$ in $O(3)$ must be the identity. But is is knon that tarnsvection are conjugates and genertate $Sl(3,R)$. So the image of $SL(3,R)$ in $O(3)$ must be trivial.

Let $C$ denote the center of $G=GL(3, \mathbb R)$, it is the group of scalar $3\times 3$ real matrices and, hence, is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^\times \cong (\mathbb R, +)\times \mathbb Z_2$.
Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Consider the intersection $N\cap C$. There are three cases which can occur: (1) $N\cap C$ has infinite index in $C$, (2) $N\cap C$ has index 2 in $C$, (3) $N$ contains $C$. (This trichotomy follows from the fact that $(\mathbb R, +)$ contains no proper subgroups of finite index.)
At the same time $O(3)\cong SO(3)\times \mathbb Z_2$ and $SO(3)$ is simple.
Let's consider the three cases separately.
(1) $N\cap C$ has infinite index in $C$. Then $G/N$ contains an infinite central subgroup (the image of $C$ in $G/N$). Thus, $G/N$ cannot be isomorphic to $O(3)$ since the center of the latter is $\mathbb Z_2$.
(3) $N$ contains $C$. if $N\cap SL(3,\mathbb R)$ is nontrivial, then, by simplicity of $SL(3,\mathbb R)$, $N$ contains $SL(3,\mathbb R)$. Thus, $N=GL(3,\mathbb R)$ and, hence, $G/N=\{1\}$.
(2) $N$ contains the index 2 subgroup in $C$. By the same argument as in (3), either $G/N\cong \mathbb Z_2$ or $N< C$. The latter is the only interesting case. Then $G/N\cong SL(3,\mathbb R)$. It remains to show that $SL(3,\mathbb R)$ is not isomorphic (as an abstract group) to $SO(3)$. To prove this one needs to know a little bit about Lie groups. For instance, every infinite nilpotent subgroup $H$ of $SO(n)$ contains an abelian group as a finite index subgroup. This can be proven as follows. Take the closure $\bar{H}$ of $H$ in $SO(n)$. This is a closed subgroup, hence, is a Lie subgroup. (This is a nontrivial result due to Cartan, true for closed subgroups of general Lie groups.) But $\bar{H}$ is also nilpotent, as the closure of a nilpotent subgroup. Since $\bar{H}$ is compact, it has only finitely many connected components. Let $\bar{H}_0$ denote the identity component of $\bar{H}$. Then
$\bar{H}_0$ is a connected nilpotent Lie subgroup of $SO(n)$. Such a subgroup has to be abelian (see for instance, this question). Even for $n=3$ this is not completely obvious, but is not hard to prove either by looking at the subalgebras of the Lie algebra ${\mathfrak o}(3)$. In any case, it follows that $H\cap  \bar{H}_0$ is an abelian subgroup of finite index in $H$. At the same time, $SL(3,\mathbb R)$ contains the subgroup of strictly upper triangular matrices. This group is 2-step nilpotent and contains no finite index subgroups. Thus, $SL(3,\mathbb R)$ is not isomorphic to $SO(3)$ as an abstract group.
